# How to import highcharts-border-radius plugin in LitElement web component?

Tags: typescript, npm, lit-element, lit

Created a web component using LitElement and created a columnrange chart using highcharts in that, now I want to add the border radius only to the top left and top right corners of the bar, and for that, I installed highcharts-border-radius external plugin to give borderRadiusTopLeft and borderRadiusTopRight, but I am not able to import this plugin in the component. After importing it, getting an error that Highcharts is not defined.

Tried importing like:

`import "highcharts-border-radius";`

I also tried using the following:

`const borderRadius = require("highcharts-border-radius");`

`borderRadius(Highcharts);`

When using the second approach, then got an error that ReferenceError: require is not defined.

Any help importing this external plugin in the LIT element would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you loading the base `highcharts`? It seems the side-effect import expects `Highcharts` to be present in global/window. You can't use `require` in the browser.

Comment: @AugustineKim I am importing base highcharts like: `import Highcharts from 'highcharts/es-modules/masters/highcharts.src.js';`

Answer (score 0):

It appears while the base highcharts package has ES module exports, the plugin `highcharts-border-radius` does not.

To use the plugin in a browser environment as is, you'll just have to make sure `Highcharts` is installed globally.

One way to do this is to also utilize the UMD version of `highcharts`

```js
import 'highcharts';
import 'highcharts-border-radius';

Highcharts.chart(...)
```